# Google indexed my website as an IP address

Tags: indexing, subdomain

I have a website : https://linuxquizapp.com.uy.
I recently used Google Search Console to index it into google but when I do a search, I get this instead:

[image]

That's the right IP but most importantly, how did the IP ended up there instead of the domain name and also, is there anything I can do to correct this?

The app is written in Go, and there is no Apache or Nginx or whatnot configuration I should change?

Note- I am including an image in the question instead of plain text or a link so this does not get "outdated" as Google indexer updates stuff.

Comment: This sounds like a question between suited to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect the IP as host based requests to the domain host.
Once you will do that, google indexes will get updated in few days to show the hostname as domain instead of IP address.

Comment: Ill test this. Thanks

Comment: I no longer have access to that EC2 instance with that IP. What  are my options

Comment: Get a new Server in AWS and try to get the same IP, if its free Amazon may give it to you